# Function mcrypt_get_iv_size() is deprecated in laravel 4.2 on PHP 5.6 server

Tags: php, laravel, mcrypt

I'm using **ubuntu 16.04** and my php version is **php5.6**.
When i run here **laravel version 4.2** project, then show a deprecated message **"Function mcrypt_get_iv_size() is deprecated"** .
But **Laravel 5.2** project is fine. There is no problem. It occurred when i run **laravel 4.2** project.

[image]

Comment: Normal procedure in this case is to look up the error message in your favourite search engine and see what the function has been replaced with. Deprecated doesn't mean it's gone, it's a warning saying they will probably remove it in a future release. The idea is you have time to make changes before it's removed. But if you just want to carry on then you can, until tool is updated.

Comment: What editor are you using? Looks cool

Comment: I'm using Sublime text editor. But here given screenshot is not from sublime or any text editor. It's default error page of laravel 4.2. @HamSam

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue.

> This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.1.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.
>
> source: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-get-iv-size.php)

You either disable *exceptions on warning* or you upgrade your Laravel project to 5.2, or you stick to a version where your Laravel project supports the PHP version you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
PHP 7.1.0 discouraged this function. But i'm using php 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

Update PHP version 7.1,

And if then you face problem, update Laravel 5 or up.